# When does there exist a subsequence which converges to the Cesaro mean

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

I have a sequence of continuous (even analytic) functions on $[0,1]$. I know that the Cesaro mean of the sequence of functions converges uniformly on $[0,1]$:
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n\rightarrow f$$
I was also able to show that this sequence is uniformly Lipschitz and bounded, so I know that there exists a subsequence of functions which converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ (using Arzela-Ascoli). I'd like to determine if there possibly exists a subsequence of functions which converges uniformly to the Cesaro mean itself ($f$). So basically I'd be happy to hear some ideas about possible criterions I could use. I am obviously not saying that there should always be a subsequence which converges to the Cesaro mean, but maybe there are some useful special cases which I can use.

At first I tried to possibly think in the direction of the Banach-Saks theorem and weak-$*$ topology. I know that the unit ball in $C([0,1])$ is weak-$*$ compact. I am actually not sure if it is weak-$*$ sequentially compact, but let's say it is. Then my bounded sequence contains a subsequence which converges in the weak-$*$ topology. Then I could maybe apply some version of Banach-Saks to show that this subsequence has a smaller subsequence which actually converges to the mean value in norm (so uniformly). But as I said, I am not sure if there is a version of Banach-Saks which applies in this case, and I am overall not sure about the details and if this should work, this was just a hunch.

Anyway, I'd be happy to hear some ideas as to what tools might come in handy and under what assumptions I can actually show something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only chance I see is that the sequence converges is some weaker  Hausdorff topology. This is probaly not very helpful. BTW, the unit ball of a Banach space $X$ is weakly compact if and only if $X$ is reflexive. Hence, the unit ball of $C([0,1])$ is not weakly compact.

Comment: @Jochen Yeah, I meant weak star closed... I'll change the mistake. By the way, could you further explain the first part of your response?

Comment: Would $f_n(x) = (-1)^n$ be a counterexample?

Comment: @daw Of course (this is also the first thing I had in mind). As I said, I am not saying that this is always true. I am looking for some nice criteria for cases in which the convergence does occur (so that I can see if some of them might apply to my case).  I am not writing here my specific case since it is a bit technical and also I think that this is generally an interesting question, so it could be good to have a 'list' of cases in which things converge.

Comment: There is no weak$^*$-topology on $C([0,1])$. This is not a dual Banach space.